# Fails in Telnet works in SSH

Tags: unix, ssh, ksh, telnet

Hi
I am connecting to a remote unix and running a command there that supposed to run in the background.

The problem is that when I am connecting with ssh it works fine but if I am connecting with telnet the program which I run stops running after a few seconds.

the program which I execute is a program that starts another program in the background.
It seems (guessing) that the failure happens when the first program is about to run the other program in the background.

has anyone encountered something like that ever?

Comment: Are you connected with the same user via telnet/ssh?

Comment: is the application running under X-windows?

Comment: I am connecting using putty using exactly same user.
no X windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[> An interactive shell is one started without non-option arguments, unless `-s` is specified, without specifying the `-c` option, and whose input and output are both connected to terminals (as determined by isatty(3)), or one started with the `-i` option. See section 6.3 Interactive Shells, for more information](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bashref.html#SEC70)

Job control isn't available over your telnet. This can be

- a deficiency of your telnet client
- a missing option to telnet
- if you start bash in a pipe, e.g., by default the input/output are not connected to a terminal (but rather pipes). Don't do that :)

[See also](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bashref.html#SEC92)

Comment: not sure I completely understand that.
I think I am using interactive shell.
I tried both Telnet of putty and of perl.

Comment: Wow... ok. Perhaps you should manually enable monitor mode (`set -m` or `set -o monitor`) [see also](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/pseries/v5r3/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.aix.baseadmn/doc/baseadmndita/korn_shell_job_ctrl.htm)

Comment: I think you might be right about job control being the issue.
when I log in using ssh and type the command bg it works but using telnet I get:
ksh: bg: no such job

Comment: anyone knows how one can enable job control for telnet with putty? please.

Comment: OK, turns out, you can't use job control with telnet. Period.
Telnet is just not designed to be a shell.